# Как вставлять автоматически значение из другой таблицы?

Tags: c#, mysql, phpmyadmin

есть таблица `teachers`, в которой столбец `kod_teacher` является первичным ключом, также есть таблица `class`, где столбец `kod_teacher` является  индексом и они связаны. как сделать так, чтобы при создании нового учителя в таблице `class` добавлялся его связанный код.

[image: Вот связь таблиц]
Также 
[image: структура таблицы]

Comment: `при создании нового учителя в таблице class` как вы это делаете?

Comment: Использовать Entity Framework DataBase first тип

Comment: не совсем понятен вопрос. Сформулируйте вопрос по новому. Что Вы хотите добавлять в таблицу class? новую строку с данными или только код учителя? Вы хотите это делать в программе или на уровне баз данных? И при чем здесь phpmyadmin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В блок try{} catch{} вешается вставка в первую таблицу, если нет ошибок - то производится вставка во вторую таблицу. В базу это делается путем создания триггера на вставку(см. литерутуру)

Comment: Спасибо огромное!